# Silex rewrite + images when in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, silex

I have my site hosted at:

domain.com/dir1/dir2

Which maps internally on the file system (symlink'd) to:

/var/www/webroot/something/web

In that directory is my app's index.php which all requests should be routed to. I have a .htaccess file in that directory with these contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

This works fine and my app functions and all urls are accessible. The problem is that the application hardcodes all the paths to the assets. For example when the HTML renders the CSS is referenced as:
`<link href="/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">` when in fact the file is physically on the file system at `/var/www/webroot/something/web/assets/css/app.css` and therefore the URL to reference the file is: `domain.com/dir1/dir2/assets/css/app.css`

Can I solve this somehow with .htaccess?

I've tried the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/dir2$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The logic behind this attempt was that i can let the first rule handle the app routing. But the second rule would make sure that any attempts to request the images load them from the correct path. Unfortunately but the request goes to the webroot of the domain the .htaccess is invalid. It's not possible for me to put a .htaccess at domain.com either.

What are my options?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Your assets use relative path isn't it ? If the URL of your site is domain.com/dir1/dir2, absolute path to assets will be domain.com/dir1/dir2/assets/

Comment: The assets use absolute paths in the HTML. The scale of making this change to replace those absolute paths to relative paths is enormous.

Comment: well, `<link href="/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">` is not absolute. Is that what you have in your HTML code at the moment ?

Comment: That's what I have. But any path that begins with / will map to the domain root, which is not where the assets directory is.

Answer (score 0):

You should prepend your assets URLs with the Request Base URL.

```
$app['request']->getBaseUrl();
```

If you are using Twig, you can use:

```
app.request.baseUrl
```

By the way, the Silex [TwigServiceProvider documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html) says:

> You must prepend the app.request.baseUrl to render calls 
>   to ensure that the render works when deployed into a sub-directory of the docroot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the path from the raw request line

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(/assets/\S+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /dir/dir2%1 [L]
```